# I would like to read in all content in a text file (but there is only one double value in textfile), convert to double and return value

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at c++. I have a text file with value: 3.0 (which changes 
for every run of my program). I would like to create a c++ function which 
open the textfile in a certain folder, and reads this value, converts into a 
double variable and returns this value, and then close the textfile.

```
//read value, convert and return
double getDoubleValueFromFile(string filename, string path) {
    string stringValue;
    double doubleValue; 

    string line;
    string concat = path + filename;
    using namespace std;

    ifstream myfile(concat);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {   
            //read value into stringValue
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    //convert stringValue to doubleValue

    return doubleValue;
}
```

Comment: The `>>` operator of all input streams can do this conversion for you. Just do `myfile >> doubleValue`. If you want to read line by line, you can construct a `std::istringstream` from `line` and read from that (`std::istringstream iss(line); iss >> doubleValue`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read lines in a loop if you are only interested in a single value at the beginning of the file. Just use `operator>>` to read that value directly be done with it:

```cpp
double getDoubleValueFromFile(string filename, string path)
{
    double doubleValue = 0.0;

    std::ifstream myfile(path + filename);
    if (myfile.is_open())
        myfile >> doubleValue;
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";

    return doubleValue;
}
```